# Ejabberd terminating without any logs

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, ejabberd

I had installed ejabberd-v19.02 from source on ubuntu-16.04.

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make install
```

Successfully registered admin user and some other users, everything working fine with default configuration and Mnesia database.
Then I had changed it to use mysql. These are the configuration fields I had changed in "ejabberd.yml" file.

```
default_db: sql

sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "password"
## If you want to specify the port:
sql_port: 3306
```

Then I rebuilt it with below commands.

```
./configure --enable-mysql
make install
```

Then I tried to start the ejabberd and it is simply terminating and not writing any logs in any of the log files (ejabberd.log, error.log, crash.log). Showing below response if I checked for the status.

```
$ ejabberdctl status

The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
ejabberd is not running in that node
Check for error messages: /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log
or other files in that directory.
```

Even I revert back those configurations and tried to run with default configuration also getting same error.

Comment: You should start ejabberd with  `ejabberdctl live` to be in interactive mode. You may get more information. It is likely that the user that you launch ejabberd with as no right to write those log files.

Comment: log files directory is already with 777 permissions.

Comment: You did not try launching in interactive mode as I suggested. You should.